# Popup Alert based on a picklist value - error message

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created a Lightning component to display a popup alert when "1" is being selected from a picklist, but I am getting an error message when trying to save

> ": unexpected token: a floating point number at column 2"

See below component:

```
<aura:component access="global">
<aura:attribute name ="1" type ="integer"/>
<ligthning:select label = "Picklistfield" name = "Picklistfield" value ="{!v.1}" onchange="{!c.openPopup}">
        <option value = "2">2</option>
        <option value = "3">3/option>
 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" onsubmit="alert('Message here');" rerender="none"/>       
</ligthning:select>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

`1` is not a legal name for an `<aura:attribute>`. From [Component Attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_attributes.htm),

> #### Attribute Naming Rules
>
> An attribute name must follow these naming rules:
>
> - Must begin with a letter or an underscore
> - Must contain only alphanumeric or underscore characters

Comment: Thanks for your reply, David. The API Names for the picklist values are numerical characters. So when the user selects "abc" (API = 1), I want to display the popup alert with a message, so this is where I was struggling.

Comment: @SSimion Your attribute should _not_ be named the same as the values of your options.